# Краш Swing-Приложения при переходе в окно игры через Alt-Tab

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем столкнулся со странной проблемой.
Данный код работает без нареканий, но когда я пытаюсь перейти в полноэкранное окно игры в данном случае (PlayerUnknown’s Battlegrounds) данная программа просто закрывается (в консоли нет ничего),но если не вызывать frame.repaint(); то программа работает без проблем.
Очень надеюсь на помощь...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(700, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    while (true) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        frame.repaint();//Это строка как-то на это влияет 

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему при помощи

frame.createBufferStrategy(4);

Answer (score 0):

Объекты Swing не [потокобезопасны](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Поэтому следует создавать фрейм в потоке диспетчерезации:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();

   frame.setSize(700, 400);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setVisible(true);
}
```